# Flutter change color of drawer scrim

Tags: dart, flutter

Is it possible o change the color or transparency of the drawer's scrim in flutter? Something like is Java's `drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`?

Thanks.

Comment: I've just sent a PR with this change , I hope it will be accepted: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/31025   Thumbs up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flutter now includes a `drawerScrimColor` parameter in the Scaffold widget.

For example:

```
Scaffold(
      drawerScrimColor: Colors.black,
);
```

Although I answered the question, @diegoveloper deserves the credit for submitting the PR

Comment: I wonder why I still get a `The named parameter 'drawerScrimColor' isn't defined`  error message. I'm using Android Studio and Flutter was just updated like an hour ago. Thanks.

Comment: What version of Flutter are you using? You'll need to be in master as of today.
Here's a link to the file. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/880015346844150bc59604f4b2dd4b2c64e61967/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart#L998-L1001

Answer (score 0):

Following the same ideia brought by @diegoveloper and for that who might wonder how to make transparency just use the transparent color `drawerScrimColor: Colors.transparent`

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Colors/transparent-constant.html

Answer (score 0):

You can change drawerTheme like this:

```
return ThemeData(
      drawerTheme: DrawerThemeData(
        scrimColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
    );
```